# generate text sequence in powershell

Tags: powershell

I just had to produce a long xml sequence for some testing purpose, a lot of elements 
like <hour>2009.10.30.00</hour>.

This made me drop into a linux shell and just run

```
for day in $(seq -w 1 30) ; do  
  for hour in $(seq -w 0 23) ; 
    do echo "<hour>2009.10.$day.$hour</hour>" ; 
  done ; 
done >out
```

How would I do the same in powershell on windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty similar...

```
$(foreach ($day in 1..30) {
    foreach ($hour in 0..23) {
        "<hour>2009.10.$day.$hour</hour>"
    }
}) > tmp.txt
```

Added file redirection. If you are familiar with bash the syntax should be pretty intuitive.

Comment: How would I redirect that output to a file ?

Answer (score 3):

If I were scripting I would probably go with orsogufo's approach for readability.  But if I were typing this at the console interactively I would use a pipeline approach - less typing and it fits on a single line e.g.:

```
1..30 | %{$day=$_;0..23} | %{"<hour>2009.10.$day.$_</hour>"} > tmp.txt
```

Comment: Using a pipeline with the Foreach-Object cmdlet (%) is more idiomatic of PowerShell than using a 'foreach' statement. 

In a script, replace the '%' with 'foreach' if you want, and break in to multiple lines.